# Error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException when accesing to HTTPS site from Lambda

Tags: json, ssl, lambda, java-8, ioexception

I'm developing a custom skill to Alexa (Amazon), and I coded the skill in lambda AWS service in JAVA 8. I'm trying to get a simple response from my ask2decide API and it's not working.

Basically I'm executing the following code:

```
String questiont = "casco"
String queryString = 
        String.format("https://www.ask2decide.com/api/prod/search.php?s=%s", questiont);

    InputStreamReader inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        String line;
        URL url = new URL(queryString);
        inputStream = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStream);
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // reset builder to a blank string
        System.out.print("ERROR:");
        System.out.println(e);

    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(inputStream);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(bufferedReader);
    }
```

The result of executing it is the following

> error:"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed
>   connection during handshake"

Note: I get a JSON standard array if I execute the URL in Chrome without any error.

Note2: The imports:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.*;
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import com.amazon.speech.slu.Intent;
import com.amazon.speech.slu.Slot;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.IntentRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.LaunchRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.Session;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SessionEndedRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SessionStartedRequest;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletV2;
import com.amazon.speech.speechlet.SpeechletResponse;
import com.amazon.speech.json.SpeechletRequestEnvelope;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.OutputSpeech;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.PlainTextOutputSpeech;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.SsmlOutputSpeech;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.Reprompt;
import com.amazon.speech.ui.SimpleCard;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONArray;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONException;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONObject;
import com.amazonaws.util.json.JSONTokener;
```

Comment: Did I miss the lambda on my way to the comments section or is it actually not yet there? Or did you mean you're finally closing quietly within the lambda block?

Comment: Hi @nullpointer, I did just a review of the question to clarify the context. Can you help me? THANKS!!!